# Excel Next Without For

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I keep getting a Next Without For error, and I cannot see why. What I'm trying to do is basically search the main worksheet for say North West, copy all of the information in that row, and then paste it over to the North West sheet.

```
Sub NorthWest()

Sheets("MASTERSHEET").Select
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Range("E" And i).Value = "North West" Then
Rows(i).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("North West").Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Next i

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Learn to properly indent your code (both here and on your own machine), and it will make this sort of problem much easier to figure out yourself.

Comment: @user2771898 see my answer below, it's copying and pasting between sheets without Selecting sheets all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ken. Thanks Shai, I will try your method - thanks so much for your input and time, its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `If` does not have an `End if`

Correct the code to be

```
If Range("E" And i).Value = "North West" Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("North West").Select
    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End If
```

and the `Next` will work

Answer (score 0):

Another option of your code, is to **avoid using** `Sheets.Select` and declare sheets variables to avoid possible errors you might get while using `ActiveSheet`.

I assumed you want multiple Copy-Paste between worksheets if Cell in **Column E** in *MASTERSHEET* equals "*North West*".

Find code below and let me know is it's working for you

```
Option Explicit

Sub NorthWest()

Dim sht_Master                  As Worksheet
Dim sht_NorthWest               As Worksheet
Dim LastRow                     As Long
Dim lrow                        As Long
Dim erow                        As Long

' set sht objects to avoid possible errors if using Active sheet
Set sht_Master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTERSHEET")
Set sht_NorthWest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("North West")

LastRow = sht_Master.Range("A" & sht_Master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lrow = 2 To LastRow

    ' I assumed you want to copy and past between sheets inside the For loop
    If sht_Master.Range("E" & lrow).Value = "North West" Then
        erow = sht_NorthWest.Cells(sht_NorthWest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        ' copy and paste between sheets without using Select
        sht_Master.Rows(lrow).Copy _
        Destination:=sht_NorthWest.Range("A" & erow)
    End If

Next lrow

End Sub
```